# Output variable not set as kubectl command output exceeded the maximum supported length. Output length: 61113, Maximum supported length: 32766

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, cicd

I want to store logs of a pod and to use later in another tasks and if the output length is less than 32766 is working but because of the output-length is greater than 32766 is not wokring.Do u have any solution for this? (DevOps Azure - ci/cd)

```
    - task: Kubernetes@1
      displayName: 'Get Job Logs'
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
        kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'Development Kubernetes '
        namespace: 'logs'
        command: 'logs'
        arguments: 'job/k6-job-shs'
      name: k6JobLogs
    - bash: |
           echo "$(k6JobLogs.KubectlOutput)" > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/k6-job-logs-shs.txt
      displayName: 'Store Job Logs'
```

The error is: ##[warning]Output variable not set as kubectl command output exceeded the maximum supported length. Output length: 61113, Maximum supported length: 32766

Answer (score 1):

Stop using the Kubernetes@1 task in this case and call kubectl from a script instead. Use output redirection there. Thus, the value will not be stored in an environment variable and no limits will be broken.

To call the kubectl command from a script, the Kubernetes@1 task with `command: login` will need to be called first.